# installing h2o/ use of Java?

Tags: java, r, h2o

**have been trying to install h2o for use on R and have hit multiple buffers....**

I seem to be able to install the file successfully by using:

```
install.packages("~/Desktop/h2o_3.18.0.1.tar.gz", repos = NULL, type = "source")
```

**Out**

```
installing *source* package ‘h2o’ ...
R
demo
inst
preparing package for lazy loading
help
installing help indices
building package indices
testing if installed package can be loaded
DONE (h2o)
```

**1. Then when I call h2o, I get an error (see below), ... I understand this may be
because it only works with earlier versions of java. Is this correct?**

**2. If so .... what should I do to get R to run an alternative version of
java?**

**(I have seen that there are people who can do this and are
describing this but I wondered if there were any concise instructions?)**

```
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘h2o’ in get(Info[i, 1],
envir = env):
 lazy-load database
'/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.4/Resources/library/h2o/R/h2o.rdb'
is corrupt
In addition: Warning message:
In get(Info[i, 1], envir = env) : internal error -3 in R_decompress1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT** If you have Java 9 but would like to use Java 7 or 8 for H2O, you can try running `Sys.setenv("JAVA_HOME", ...)` in R before running `h2o.init()`, where you specify the path to Java 7 or 8 where I have left it as `...`

If you have an internet connection try following the instructions on the [downloads page](http://h2o-release.s3.amazonaws.com/h2o/rel-wolpert/1/index.html) (select Install in R tab)

Please also post what version of Java you have.

basically run all of the following lines of code:

```
# The following two commands remove any previously installed H2O packages for R.
if ("package:h2o" %in% search()) { detach("package:h2o", unload=TRUE) }
if ("h2o" %in% rownames(installed.packages())) { remove.packages("h2o") }

# Next, we download packages that H2O depends on.
pkgs <- c("RCurl","jsonlite")
for (pkg in pkgs) {
if (! (pkg %in% rownames(installed.packages()))) { install.packages(pkg) }
}

# Now we download, install and initialize the H2O package for R.
install.packages("h2o", type="source", repos="http://h2o-release.s3.amazonaws.com/h2o/rel-wolpert/1/R")

# Finally, let's load H2O and start up an H2O cluster
library(h2o)
h2o.init()
```

Comment: I tried this also. The package gets installed, I can load it into the environment but then when I try h2o.init(), there is another error message (see below). I am fairly sure that java is the source of the problem because it states as such in the system requirements. (The only doubt is some other error message I get). I made some steps to try to load a different version of java but then this led to a layer of other problems...

Comment: ´Starting H2O JVM and connecting:
[1] "localhost"
[1] 54321
[1] TRUE
[1] -1

Comment: [1] "Failed to connect to localhost port 54321: Connection refused"
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0curl: (7) Failed to connect to localhost port 54321: Connection refused
[1] 7
Error in h2o.init(nthreads = -1) : 
  H2O failed to start, stopping execution.´

Comment: my version of java is 9

Comment: ah okay, yes java 9 is not currently supported by h2o, you would need to use Java 7 or 8.

Comment: Is there a way I can use H2O in R with java 7 or 8 such that my overall java will remain the same but it will run the relevant java just for the H2O-process? I have seen people talk about this but I do not know how to do it.

Comment: I updated my answer to include your request, hopefully this will work for you.